# Interactive video with simulation using Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video, interactive

I have created a few simple simulations using the canvas tag, and now I would like to embed similar types of simulations on a mp4 file so that I can create an e-learning interactive video. Does anyone know how this can be done? Some websites are great (like H5P) but don't allow interactive simulations.

I'd like some advice: should I try and place a video in the canvas tag? Or should I try and overlay the simulation on top of a video? Does anyone know any code I can use to get started?

Thanks so much, and sorry if this is a simple question - I'm pretty new to HTML/JS

Here's an example of a simulation I've made:

https://virtuallypassedsmartsparrow.github.io/1DoF-Vibration-Q1/Draganddrop.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not easily run a mp4 on Canvas. But u can use the Pixi.Js for advanced use of Canvas Renderer.

https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/video.js